# Как передать значение элемента radio через socketio на flask?

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2, socketio

Есть переключатель на два значения (on off) и необходимо через js используя socketio и jinja2 передать его значение на flask. А при перезагрузке страницы вывести его в правильное положение. Есть какие-нибудь решения?

Comment: 1. Использовать socketio чтобы затем перезагрузить страницу?
2. Так, чую это лаба?
3. Давай сюда МИНИМАЛЬНЫЙ пример.

Comment: К сожалению, не лаба. Для передачи хочу использовать именно JQuery, но и понятия не имею как сделать систему сообщений.

Comment: Э.. , а `socketio` ?

Comment: Нет хороших мануалов по двустороннему общению элементов

Comment: ........Хорошо.